# Objective-C: check if view touches another view

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface, view

I animate a lot of views using `(..) [UIView commitAnimations]`.
Now i want to check if the view, which was "shot", has touched another view.
Does anyone know how to implement this?
Maybe `if(view.frame.origin.x==anotherview.frame.origin.x){
}` ..

Answer (score 23):

Conceptually, a view "touches" another view if their bounding rects intersect. So to compare the bounding rects of two views, you want to do something like:

```
Boolean viewsOverlap = CGRectIntersectsRect(viewA.bounds, viewB.bounds);
```

But that alone won't work because the bounding rects of the views are specified in their own coordinate spaces (meaning both start at `0,0`, etc. etc.) So you also need to transform the rects to a common coordinate space before you compare them:

```
CGRect boundsA = [viewA convertRect:viewA.bounds toView:nil];
CGRect boundsB = [viewB convertRect:viewB.bounds toView:nil];
Boolean viewsOverlap = CGRectIntersectsRect(boundsA, boundsB);
```

From there, you should be able to figure out how to iterate efficiently through your list of views-you-care-about to determine if any overlap.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you could just compare the frames if they're in the same superview:

```
BOOL methodB = CGRectIntersectsRect(viewA.frame, viewB.frame);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var view1 = NSView()
var view2 = NSView()
var a = self.view.convert(view1.bounds, to: self.view)
var b = self.view.convert(view2.bounds, to: self.view)
a.intersects(b)
```

Comment: While it doesn't change the answer too much, note that the quesition is tagged iOS, not macOS.